# Java Clone Class With Primitive Types

Tags: java, clone

I am trying to create a deep copy of an `Object` (called `State`) to do modifications to one of the instances within it, then follow up with code that modifies the old `State` based on the new `State`.

Here is `State`:

```
public class State implements Cloneable {

    // 0: empty
    // 1: white
    // 2: black
    private int[][] board;

    private int player;

    public State(int[][] board, int player) {
        this.board = board;
        this.player = player;
    }

    public int[][] getBoard() {
        return board;
    }

    public int getPlayer() {
        return player;
    }

    public void setBoard(int[][] board) {
        this.board = board;
    }

    public void setPlayer(int player) {
        this.player = player;
    }

    @Override
    protected Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        return super.clone();
    }

}
```

Then, here is how I try and access it:

```
State temp = (State) s.clone();
Action act = determineAction(temp);
doSomething(s, act);
```

`s` is a `State` passed into the method.  After `determineAction` is called, for some reason the `board` in `s` is being modified along with `temp` even though it is not passed...  How come this is?  Shouldn't the call to `.clone()` clone instances of all primitive types such that they can be uniquely modified?

That is what this post suggests:  http://howtodoinjava.com/core-java/cloning/a-guide-to-object-cloning-in-java/

I'm struggling to see why this wouldn't be deep copied, and why my modifications to `temp` would also modify `s`.

Any tips would be greatly appreciated -- thanks!

Edit - For anyone curious, here's what fixed it:

```
@Override
protected Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {

    State cloned = (State) super.clone();

    int[][] clonedBoard = new int[8][8];

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
            clonedBoard[i][j] = board[i][j];
        }
    }

    cloned.setBoard(clonedBoard);

    return cloned;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`super.clone()` does not do a deep-copy, and an `int[][]` is not a primitive type.

It works for the `int player` because that is a primitive type and a simple copy (as done by `Object#clone`) is enough.

You need to (deep-) copy your `int[][]` yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Deep cloning for Primitive data types. You can achieve deep cloning using serialization also